# Протоколы удаленного доступа к рабочему столу

Tags: delphi

Нужна помощь! В написании программы использующая vnc rdp для удаленного управления рабочим столом.
Желательно на Делфи

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с RDP в Windows есть ActiveX контрол MsRdpClient. Подробная информация по использованию доступна на MSDN: [Using the Remote Desktop ActiveX Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383541(v=VS.85).aspx). Этот контрол доступен в Delphi.